# Sign In prompt with javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have this sign in prompt that allows the user to enter a valid email address and then enter a password consisting of at least one number, one special character and at least 8 or more characters. Then the user would enter the password again, and the code ensures that it matches. It also implements a strength meter to tell the user how strong the password is.

I have the meter implementing strength based on the characters entered but, I cannot figure out how to implement the length of the password. Right now if the user enters a letter, number, and special character it states that it is strong. But I need it to also have at least 8 characters as well.

This is the specific function that I believe needs adjusting;

```
// Function for password strength meter
  function PasswordMeter(password) {
      if (password.length === 0) {
          document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "";
          return;
       }
       var matchedCase = new Array();
       matchedCase.push("[$@$!%*#?&]"); // Special Charector
       matchedCase.push("[0-9]");      // Numbers
       matchedCase.push("[a-z]");     // Lowercase Alphabates

       var ctr = 0;
       for (var i = 0; i < matchedCase.length; i++) {
            if (new RegExp(matchedCase[i]).test(password)) {
                ctr++;
            }
       }

       var color = "";
       var strength = "";
       switch (ctr) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
                 strength = "Weak: Keep going...";
                 color = "red";
                 break;
            case 2:
                 strength = "Medium: A little better but add more..";
                 color = "blue";
                 break;
            case 3:
                 strength = "Strong! Now that is good!";
                 color = "green";
                 break;
       }
       document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = strength;
       document.getElementById("msg").style.color = color;
 }
```

And just for better perspective this is the rest of my code... I am so close to this being perfect just need a little guidance on this one piece, so thank you in advance for any advice/help!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

</style>

</head>
<body>

<h3>Sign In</h3>

<div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
  
    <label for="userId">UserId:</label>
    <input type="email" id="userId" name="email" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$" required>
<br>
<br>
    <label for="psw1">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="psw1" name="psw1" pattern="(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_=+-]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number, one special character and at least 8 or more characters" onkeyup="PasswordMeter(this.value);"/><span id="msg"></span>
<br>
<br>
    <label for="psw2">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="psw2" name="psw2" pattern="(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_=+-]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number, one special character and at least 8 or more characters" required>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

<script>

//Function to check if email is valid.

function validateEmail(userId) {
    var re = /\S+@\S+/;
    return re.test(email);
}
userId.onchange = validateEmail;
userId.onkeyup = validateEmail;


// Function to check if both passwords is same or not. 
var password = document.getElementById("psw1"), psw2 = document.getElementById("psw2");

function validatePassword(){
  if(psw1.value != psw2.value) {
    psw2.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
  } else {
    psw2.setCustomValidity('');
  }
}

psw1.onchange = validatePassword;
psw2.onkeyup = validatePassword;

// Function for password strength meter
  function PasswordMeter(password) {
      if (password.length === 0) {
          document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "";
          return;
       }
       var matchedCase = new Array();
       matchedCase.push("[$@$!%*#?&]"); // Special Charector
       matchedCase.push("[0-9]");      // Numbers
       matchedCase.push("[a-z]");     // Lowercase Alphabates

       var ctr = 0;
       for (var i = 0; i < matchedCase.length; i++) {
            if (new RegExp(matchedCase[i]).test(password)) {
                ctr++;
            }
       }

       var color = "";
       var strength = "";
       switch (ctr) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
                 strength = "Weak: Keep going...";
                 color = "red";
                 break;
            case 2:
                 strength = "Medium: A little better but add more..";
                 color = "blue";
                 break;
            case 3:
                 strength = "Strong! Now that is good!";
                 color = "green";
                 break;
       }
       document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = strength;
       document.getElementById("msg").style.color = color;
 }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your regex is already checking that the password length is at least 8 characters. The only thing you have to do is to display a message if this length is below 8 characters. I overrided the 'strength' variable with the new message, but you could also display a new one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

</style>

</head>
<body>

<h3>Sign In</h3>

<div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
  
    <label for="userId">UserId:</label>
    <input type="email" id="userId" name="email" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$" required>
<br>
<br>
    <label for="psw1">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="psw1" name="psw1" pattern="(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_=+-]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number, one special character and at least 8 or more characters" onkeyup="PasswordMeter(this.value);"/><span id="msg"></span>
<br>
<br>
    <label for="psw2">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="psw2" name="psw2" pattern="(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_=+-]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number, one special character and at least 8 or more characters" required>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

<script>

//Function to check if email is valid.

function validateEmail(userId) {
    var re = /\S+@\S+/;
    return re.test(email);
}
userId.onchange = validateEmail;
userId.onkeyup = validateEmail;


// Function to check if both passwords is same or not. 
var password = document.getElementById("psw1"), psw2 = document.getElementById("psw2");

function validatePassword(){
  if(psw1.value != psw2.value) {
    psw2.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
  } else {
    psw2.setCustomValidity('');
  }
}

psw1.onchange = validatePassword;
psw2.onkeyup = validatePassword;

// Function for password strength meter
  function PasswordMeter(password) {
      
      // here is the only part I modified
      if (password.length === 0) {
          document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "";
          return;
       } else if (password.length < 8) {
              document.getElementById("msg").style.color = 'red';
              document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Your password must be at least 8 characters long";
              return;
              
       }
       
       var matchedCase = new Array();
       matchedCase.push("[$@$!%*#?&]"); // Special Charector
       matchedCase.push("[0-9]");      // Numbers
       matchedCase.push("[a-z]");     // Lowercase Alphabates

       var ctr = 0;
       for (var i = 0; i < matchedCase.length; i++) {
            if (new RegExp(matchedCase[i]).test(password)) {
                ctr++;
            }
       }

       var color = "";
       var strength = "";
       switch (ctr) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
                 strength = "Weak: Keep going...";
                 color = "red";
                 break;
            case 2:
                 strength = "Medium: A little better but add more..";
                 color = "blue";
                 break;
            case 3:
                 strength = "Strong! Now that is good!";
                 color = "green";
                 break;
       }
       
       
       document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = strength;
       document.getElementById("msg").style.color = color;
 }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems so easy, now that I see it.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't hesitate to mark the topic as answered by checking the tick mark

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to use different regular expressions for different strength passwords. Most regex engines have a feature called "lookarounds". They are basically assertions. I will provide you with an example using lookahead assertions.

```
var isEightCharactersLong = '(?=.{8,})';
var hasNumbers = '(?=.*[0-9])';
var hasLowerCase = '(?=.*[a-z])';
var hasUpperCase = '(?=.*[A-Z])';
// we're escaping the regex reserved characters using '\'
var hasSpecialCharacters = '(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&])';
```

You can then use them to create more complex regular expressions by combining them:

```
// For ES6 with template strings
// 8 characters long AND has numbers AND (has lowercase OR has uppercase)
const weakPasswordRegex = new RegExp(
  `^${isEightCharactersLong}${hasNumbers}(${hasLowerCase}|${hasUpperCase})$`);

// For lower ES versions
var weakPasswordRegex = new RegExp(
   '^' + isEightCharactersLong + hasNumbers + '(' + hasLowerCase + '|' + hasUpperCase + ')$'
```

You can also extract the password strength measurement into a separate function:

```
function measurePasswordStrength(password) {
  var weakPassword = new RegExp('<placeholder>');
  var mediumPassword = new RegExp('<placeholder>');
  var strongPassword = new RegExp('<placeholder>');
  if (strongPassword.test(password)) return 3;
  if (mediumPassword.test(password)) return 2;
  if (weakPassword.test(password)) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Then your PasswordMeter becomes a lot more readable and understandable:

```
function PasswordMeter(password) {
  if (password.length === 0) {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }

  var color = "";
  var strength = "";
  switch (measurePasswordStrength(password)) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
      strength = "Weak: Keep going...";
      color = "red";
      break;
    case 2:
      strength = "Medium: A little better but add more..";
      color = "blue";
      break;
    case 3:
      strength = "Strong! Now that is good!";
      color = "green"; 
      break;
  }

  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = strength;
  document.getElementById("msg").style.color = color;
}
```